# pwd zsh: permission denied: /Users/myName

Tags: python, zsh, macos-big-sur, pwd

I am new to Python and I wanted to try coldtype to play with variable fonts (https://coldtype.goodhertz.com/install.html), but when I type `~ $ pwd` in terminal i get `zsh: permission denied: /Users/myName`. I already enabled `auto_cd` in `~/.zshrc` but I still get the same error.

(i have Big Sur macOS)

Comment: `~` expands to you home directory. You can't "execute" a directory, since a directory is not a program. By turning on `auto_cd`, a lone `~` would indeed work (and cd into your home directory), but by adding additional parameters (`$` and `pwd`), you disable the auto_cd-feature for this command.  It's not clear to me what you want to achieve with this command.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you copied that from an example.  The `~ $` part is just showing you what the prompt might look like.  The part you're supposed to type is just `pwd`.